Load determination for solar system
I have to do a project for a big farm (wine, fruit, etc.) where they want to install solar and so drop their electricity costs. How do I start with determining loads of buildings and facilities so that I can know where the most power is used and so the most power can be saved?
And how does one calculate the total load a building or facility represents for a power supply system?

do you have a choice of locations where to place the solar panels?

a solar system is this https://duckduckgo.com/?q=solar+system&iax=images&ia=images

What do they use electricity for? motors? heating? hot water? Would a solar thermal system be applicable?

Start at the utility meter.
Log the kWh readings every day or every hour so that you can get the usage profile. If the farm has a smart meter the utility company may be able to supply you the raw data in 15 or 30 minute periods.

How do I start with determining loads of buildings and facilities so that I can know where the most power is used and so the most power can be saved?

You need to have a very clear agreement with the customer of what their requirements and expectations are. Installing solar power does not save energy (on its own). It just reduces the cost of the energy by some factor.
If energy use reduction is required then you need to do a power usage survey.

And how does one calculate the total load a building or facility represents for a power supply system?

If the buildings are individual connections to the grid then each will have a utility energy meter. Use that. If not, you are back to an energy survey using clamp-on meters, etc.
